# ASP.NET MVC2 Dynamic HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a discussion forum/blog engine working with web forms. Each post contains html entered within an editor that is stored as an nvarchar in SQL server. When I display this in a view, like so:

```
<%#Eval("body")%>
```

The eval function escapes the html, so I gt &lt, &gt, yada yada yada. Anyone know a good way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it can help, but `HtmlDecode` is an option.